# How to give execution order for pthreads in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

There are three pthreads.

and I wanna add a thread that set the order of threads.

in my source code, i get random results.

ex)

1
2
2
1
1
3
3
3

but i want,
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3

how to do it using a addtional pthread?

Thanks to read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *runner1(void *argument) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("1 ");
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *runner2(void *argument) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("2 ");
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *runner3(void *argument) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("3 ");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;
    pthread_t t3;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, runner1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, runner2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t3, NULL, runner3, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    pthread_join(t3, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the point of using parallelism if you only need synchronous code?

Comment: maybe you can update your question to specify exactly what is the need you are trying to fullfill

Comment: Three semaphores, one unit, pass it on.

Comment: thanks to ur comment, i'm making cpu scheduling simulator.
so i wonder how to give an order of execution for threads